# print webpage source from HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, python, html, beautifulsoup, html-agility-pack

I'm new to C# coming from a python background. I've had a hard time figuring this out. In python I can use beautifulsoup to do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r).prettify
print soup
```

This gets the source content of stackoverflow.com, and prints it in to the console.
I CANNOT figure out how to do this in C#.

```
        var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
        var document = webGet.Load("http://stackoverflow.com");
        Console.WriteLine(document);
```

This does not work, it only prints the type of var document. Does anyone know how to do this? It would be much appreciated - I'm trying to learn C# by converting one of my python programs, just fyi.

Comment: When using HtmlAgilityPack, it *really* helps to know the .NET framework's built-in XmlDocument class. They have nearly the same API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `OuterHtml` property of the `DocumentNode`:

```
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
var document = webGet.Load("http://stackoverflow.com");
Console.WriteLine(document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
```